# When moving tkinter object other image disappears

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

Both items will move fine however, whenever I am using the bound keys to the event handler the other image (enemy) will disappear until i stop moving the player with the keys. Is there a way around this? I've tried the canvas method .move also and tried searching didn't find a solution from the searches I tried.

```
def move_player(self, event):
    if event.keysym.lower() == "a":
        self.player_x -= self.player_delta_x
    if event.keysym.lower() == "d":
        self.player_x += self.player_delta_x
    self.canvas.delete(self.player)
    self.make_player()

def move_enemy(self):

    self.enemy_x += self.enemy_delta_x
    self.enemy_y -= self.enemy_delta_y

    #Keep the enemy within the bounds of the screen
    if self.enemy_x > self.width - self.enemy_radius:
        self.enemy_delta_x *= -1

    if self.enemy_x < 0:
        self.enemy_delta_x *= -1

    if (self.enemy_y >= height / 2 or 
        self.enemy_y <= 0 + self.enemy_radius):

        self.enemy_delta_y *= -1

    self.canvas.delete(self.enemy)
    self.make_enemy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg = "black")
    width = root.winfo_screenwidth()

    height = root.winfo_screenheight() - TASKBAR_OFFSET
    root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
    game = Game(root, canvas, width, height)
    game.make_menu()
    game.make_background()
    game.make_player()
    game.make_enemy()
    while True:
        game.move_enemy()
        game.canvas.update()
        time.sleep(0.025)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: figured it out needed to remove the self.canvas.delete in the move player function

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of using a `while True` loop, use `root.after(0, animateFunction)`.

And then inside of the animate function:

```
def animateFunction():

#Movement Code
moveEnemyFunction()
checkPlayerMovement()

root.after(animateFunction, 10)
```

If you loop like this, it should complete the movement task each frame and ultimately move the player without losing the enemy each frame the player moves.
Now, there is no guarantee this will work, because I have no idea how your movement works and how you bound it, but I believe this should solve your problem.